# Wrong bind on aspx from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Got a problem with bind some data on a bootstrap carousel. Data set perfectly, but the bind on HTML fail.
 Here the jQuery snippet:

```
function OnSuccessNews(response) {
var news = response.d;
$(news).each(function (item) {
    $("#notizie").append("<div class=\"item container\">");
    $("#notizie").append("<h4>" + news[item].Title + "</h4>");
    $("#notizie").append("<p>" + news[item].Text + "</p>");
    $("#notizie").append("<div class=\"post\"></div>");
    $("#notizie").append("</div>");
});
$('.item').first().addClass('active');
$('#carouselNews').carousel();
}
```

Then the aspx page:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="carousel slide" id="carouselNews">
            <div class="carousel-inner" id="notizie"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is: I must to bind some news (with a title and text) in the bootstrap carousel, cycle endless the news in couple.
 Now this code show me all the data in news and no cycle. How to display 2 news a time and cycle the next news?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this :

```
function OnSuccessNews(response) {
var news = response.d;
$(news).each(function (item) {
    var container = $("<div class=\"item container\"></div>");

    container.append("<h4>" + news[item].Title + "</h4>");
    container.append("<p>" + news[item].Text + "</p>");
    container.append("<div class=\"post\"></div>");
    $("#notizie").append(container);
});
$('.item').first().addClass('active');
$('#carouselNews').carousel();
}
```

create a container and put data inside the container and append it to `$("#notizie)`

Comment: Partially works. Still see all the data bind. I think that `$('.item').first().addClass('active')`; does not work as it should: if I add in `var container = $("<div class=\"item container\"></div>");` the active class, show all, if I remove show none - Ok, found the problem, it search the first `item` in the DOM, and found the 1st of 3 carousel (mine is the last, and got another doto customization on 2nd position). I just flag in the class a custom flag.

Comment: try this : $("#carouselNews .item:first).addClass('active')

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, Get the `innerHTML` of your target `div` and add all the element to that `div` and finally add the `innerHTML` to created HTML string

```
 HTML = document.getElementById('notizie').innerHTML;
 $(news).each(function (item) {
      HTML += "<div class=\"item container\"></div>";
      HTML += "<h4>" + news[item].Title + "</h4>";
      HTML += "<p>" + news[item].Text + "</p>";
      HTML += "<div class=\"post\"></div>";
 });
document.getElementById('notizie').innerHTML = HTML;
```